# User connects to but does not authenticate with mysql database

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a Desktop Application that accesses a mysql db. The login information is embedded and from MySQL workbench I see it connect but it times out trying to authenticate. This only happens inside their office network. I am assuming some type of issue with a firewall. Can anyone give me some tips as to how to properly troubleshoot and resolve this issue?

Comment: Post the connection string. You need to ensure the port is open to allow Tcp/IP connections, by default it is 3306

Comment: It probably doesn't time out during authentication. If it's timing out, the client software probably is not able to connect (as Lloyd mentioned, over TCP port 3306) to the server.  The server will reject an incorrect authentication attempt promptly without a timeout.

Answer (score 0):

The issue ended up being a firewall issue on their end. I had no access to it and they swore they were not blocking the ports. 
But once the firewall unit was disconnected they could connect fine.
Thanks to all that tried to help. This was a wierd one where I was not being given correct information from the IT team of the client.